# Varien Profiler won't turn on for front end

Tags: magento-1.9, profiler

I am using magento 1.9.3 and I have followed all the steps to turn on Varien Profiler but when I go to the frontend it still won't show up.

1) enabled it in system -> configuration -> advanced -> developer -> debug(profiler) = enabled

2) Varien_Profiler::enable() is uncommented in index.php

3) Cleared cache

I also have https://www.mgt-commerce.com/magento-developer-toolbar.html and its worth noting that the toolbar is showing up in the admin section but not on the frontend.

I have also enabled sql profiling.

Any idea what I am missing?

***UPDATE***

The allowed IP's is blank for every configuration. Also, its worth noting that im using a custom theme. However, turning this theme off and going to default or rwd doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Check system -> configuration -> advanced -> developer -> Developer Client Restrictions >  Allowed IPs (comma separated)  have blank value or your ip, check also with changing store.

Comment: blank for each configuration. I've tried adding my IP address in there in the past just to see if that changed anything but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have encountered the same issue for the **Mgt Commerce Developer Toolbar** extension, and solved it  like this:

> Copy frontend extension files in **frontend/rwd/default** instead of
>   **frontend/default/default** as stated in the extension instructions.

Our installation was **Magento 1.9.3.7** with **Sample Data 1.9.2.4** included on, Windows 10 platform with XAMPP installed.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup not only the Profiler but the configuration scope. Every scope has a profiler setting. See the top left corner select box (current configuration scope) in the admin.